# How to expand parent-child hierarchy recursively using CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database, common-table-expression

I am trying to expand a self-referencing table using a CTE in an Azure SQL database but didn't get it to work yet.

The origin table has columns Id, ParentId, for example:

```
Id    ParentId
1     NULL
2     1
3     2
4     2
5     4
6     4
7     NULL
8     7
```

The result I want is this: (a row for each id and it's child or grandchild or ...)

```
Id    ChildId
1     1
1     2
1     3
1     4
1     5
1     6
2     2
2     3
2     4
2     5
2     6
3     3
4     4
4     5
4     6
5     5
6     6
7     7
7     8
8     8
```

Any way to do this using CTE or perhaps a SQL table-valued function?

Comment: As Azure SQL Database has compatibility with SQL Server i also included the SQL Server tag..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a recursive CTE for this:

```
with cte as (
      select id, id as childid, 1 as lev
      from t
      -- where parentid is null
      union all
      select cte.id, t.id, lev + 1
      from cte join
           t
           on cte.childid = t.parentid
      where lev < 10 and t.id <> cte.id
     )
select id, childid
from cte
order by id, childid;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=28ece872026a168e0673340a861faff3) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

I would use the example code in the above link as a starting point. This snippet of code relies on the popular AdventureWorks database.

**F. Using a recursive common table expression to display a hierarchical list**

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;  
GO  
WITH DirectReports(Name, Title, EmployeeID, EmployeeLevel, Sort)  
AS (SELECT CONVERT(varchar(255), e.FirstName + ' ' + e.LastName),  
        e.Title,  
        e.EmployeeID,  
        1,  
        CONVERT(varchar(255), e.FirstName + ' ' + e.LastName)  
    FROM dbo.MyEmployees AS e  
    WHERE e.ManagerID IS NULL  
    UNION ALL  
    SELECT CONVERT(varchar(255), REPLICATE ('|    ' , EmployeeLevel) +  
        e.FirstName + ' ' + e.LastName),  
        e.Title,  
        e.EmployeeID,  
        EmployeeLevel + 1,  
        CONVERT (varchar(255), RTRIM(Sort) + '|    ' + FirstName + ' ' +   
                 LastName)  
    FROM dbo.MyEmployees AS e  
    JOIN DirectReports AS d ON e.ManagerID = d.EmployeeID  
    )  
SELECT EmployeeID, Name, Title, EmployeeLevel  
FROM DirectReports   
ORDER BY Sort;
```

**AdventureWorks schema**

A Visio ER diagram can be obtained from here
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=10331